# Cutting a folder from url with .htaccess, said folder can be anywhere in the url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have thoroughly searched for ways to remove a folder that is in the middle of the url, as shown in the example below:

What I have:

```
http://www.website.com/company/pages/section/content
```

I want to get rid of the /pages/ part, so that it appears like this:

```
http://www.website.com/company/section/content
```

It is worth noting that I already use a bit of .htaccess, to remove the .php extension from appearing, so maybe this clashes with the required redirection? Here's what I use to remove .php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

---

The solutions I have found so far seem to work great if you are trying to remove the folder that acts as root after the url, but the /pages/ folder can literally be at any level in the urls of the website I work on (sometimes they're at the root, sometimes after /company/, sometimes after /company/data/, etc). The only predictable thing is the name of the folder, which will always be "/pages".

For reference, this is the method I have tried that did not work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can provide help.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? Is `/company` a real directory? Also show your full .htaccess in question

Comment: The .htaccess is located at the root (http://www.website.com/). Current htaccess: Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(company)/((?!pages/).+)$ $1/pages/$2.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. With this, I get an error instead of the page: Not Found The requested URL /company/pages/section/content was not found on this server.

Comment: With the added R, the page does load correctly, but /pages/ is still in the url. Maybe I should try reinstalling my Apache, seems like my problem is something that should not be happening.

Comment: No, working on a company's website that was built from scratch by someone else.

Comment: Yes, if there was no .htaccess, the actual url is /company/pages/section/content.php

Comment: It still did not remove /pages/. Thanks a lot for the help, I think I'll try to simply rebuild the website differently to have a more sensible folder structure, and reinstall apache to be sure nothing's wrong there.

Comment: To test this, you need to enter URL as: **`http://www.website.com/company/section/content`**

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /pages/
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*) /company/section/content/$1 [L,R=301]
```

if this not work than try this one

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /pages/company/section/content/
RewriteRule ^pages/company/section/content/(.*) /company/section/content/$1 [L,R=301]
```